# Warning with footnotes: "name{Hfootnote.xx} has been referenced but does not exist"

Tags: hyperref, footnotes, warnings

First, some general details about my document: I'm using the `scrbook` class and the `hyperref` package. The document is split up into different source files (though this fact should not matter in this case).

I constantly get a warning for all of my footnotes (180 in total):

```
Document.tex:0. name{Hfootnote.xx} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one.
```

where the `xx` is replaced by the number of the footnote in the compiled document and is running from 1 to 180 (in my case with 180 footnotes).

The numbering of the footnotes is correct and they appear in the compiled PDF as they should.

The only problem is, that the reference in the document is wrong. Clicking on the index of a footnote (in the text) always brings one to the very first page of the document.

**What have I already tried/checked?**

- none of the footnotes is in a table or caption
- numerous recompiling does not solve any of the warnings
- some footnotes do contain `\url{}` but by far not all

Does anybody have got some hints what else I should check?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. I took the liberty to shorten the title a little bit, so that it fits better in the site layout.

Comment: It would be very good if you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem, i.e. create a minimized version of your document which still shows the warnings. You can do this by making a copy and remove all unrelated text and packages. You might even find the cause during this, because often it is some incompatibility with some other package.

Comment: Thank you @Martin. Ulrike's hint was somehow easier and faster ;) Nevertheless, the MWE-method you mentioned is worth a try for other problems.

Comment: K.: Sure if you already found the error there is no need for that effort any longer. See the MWE link above for more tips.

Comment: Although the problem was solved, I want to add something: "numerous recompiling does not solve any of the warnings": Sometimes it can also be helpful to *delete* the auxiliary files and then recompile.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Well the following works fine. So you should try to find out what your document is doing differently.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
abc\newpage abc\footnote{blub}
\end{document}
```

My guess is that you are not following the rule "load hyperref as the last package" and that something is redefining footnote.

Comment: Wow! Thank you a lot @Ulrike! That was the problem. I was loading hyperref prior to packages as fancyhdr, epstopdf and graphicx.

Comment: "My guess is that you are not following the rule "load hyperref as the last package" and that something is redefining footnote"
this was the clue that I found the problem in my code as well, I googled and came to this question and answer, thanks very much for you guys. I think an expert knowledge based on EXPERIENCE is always helpful.

Comment: @Mammatt: thank your for your comment. It was posted as answer, so I converted it to a comment to Ulrike's answer. A Q&A site is different to forums, which work with threads.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Load it before cleveref?

Comment: In my case my problem was that I actually DID load hyperref as last package, when another package should have been loaded even later. The offending package was _doi_. [This page](http://www.texblog.net/hyperref/) shows a (long) list of packages that must be loaded _after_ hyperref. -- once again the TeX/LaTeX architecture shows how outdated and hilariously fragile it is :(

Answer (score 12):

I ran into a similar problem.  Same warning, and same result (footnote links point always point to first page).  [Turns out, there’s some weird interaction between `setspace` and `hyperref`.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/188273)  The solution is to make sure `setspace` is loaded *before* `hyperref`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
Hi.\footnote{Yolo}
\end{document}
```

Otherwise, if you swap the order, it will cause that same warning.

Note: `bookmark` also uses `hyperref` under the hood so a similar problem can arise even if you don’t use `hyperref` explicitly.

Comment: In my case, this was complicated by the fact that the documentclass loaded hyperref. Here is a workaround I found that doesn't require modifying the class: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/462612/123144

Answer (score 7):

I had this issue as well, so I went with the `\footnotemark[n]` where I placed the footnote, then later on in the document: `\footnotetext[n]{text}`.

I think it was because of the command I placed the footnote in, that it was not working as expected. Outside of the `tabular` and `textit` brackets, `\footnote` worked fine.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.