# Hyperref is loaded by the class, and I need to load packages that are supposed to be loaded before

Tags: floats, hyperref, packages, incompatibility

I am using the `lipics` documentclass, which loads `hyperref`. Since I want my figures boxed, I added the following

```
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{boxed}
\restylefloat{figure}
```

The problem: I receive warnings of the kind

```
name{figure.1} has been referenced but does not exist,replaced by a fixed one
```

which use to happen when I load the `float` package after `hyperref`.

The question: is there any correct way to do this without redefining the class?

Comment: Have a look at this question: [which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before). As @BrentLongborough once put it brilliantly, the best place for loading `hyperref` package is after `\end{document}` :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, I added:

```
\RequirePackage{fooPackage}
\PassOptionsToPackage{bookmarks=false}{hyperref}
```

BEFORE `\documentclass`, which fixed the issue I was having without modifying the class.

Comment: This is a good option if it is possible (it might not always work because the loading order requires more than just "load before `hyperref`" or because the `hyperref` options get mangled or reset in the class).

Answer (score 10):

Short version: yes, you'll have to redefine the class, or at least patch their `hyperref` inclusion.

I ran into a similar problem with my `hyperref`-using thesis class (which was originally a package). When it was a package, I could have students load packages before or after my thesis package, and `hyperref` would then be in the right order. Once I made a class, though, *all* my packages would be loaded first in the `\documentclass` line, which made it impossible for anyone to work around `hyperref`. Rather than abandon `hyperref` entirely, I added the following to the class:

```
\IfFileExists{\jobname-packages-loaded-before-hyperref.sty}{%
  \RequirePackage{\jobname-packages-loaded-before-hyperref}
}{}

% For all sorts of hyperlinks in the PDF output.
\RequirePackage[pdfcreator={pdfLaTeX with hyperref},
  plainpages=false,
  pdfpagelabels,
  hypertexnames=true,
  colorlinks=false]{hyperref}

\IfFileExists{\jobname-packages-loaded-after-hyperref.sty}{%
  \RequirePackage{\jobname-packages-loaded-after-hyperref}%
}{}
```

and now my students just have to put all their extra `\usepackage` or `\RequirePackage` entries in one of two .sty files. Examples: [before package](http://trac.cae.tntech.edu/ttuthesis/browser/trunk/thesis-packages-loaded-before-hyperref.sty?rev=71), [after package](http://trac.cae.tntech.edu/ttuthesis/browser/trunk/thesis-packages-loaded-after-hyperref.sty?rev=71), and [class](http://trac.cae.tntech.edu/ttuthesis/browser/trunk/ttuthesis.cls?rev=71).

Answer (score 8):

It is well-known (and should be to class authors) that `hyperref` needs to be loaded as late as possible. Hence, the class should really be changed not to load `hyperref`.

Answer (score 4):

In the [KOMA-Script-bundle](http://www.komascript.de), Markus Kohm’s replacement for the standard LaTeX-classes and much more, he includes a package called `scrlfile`, that is designed to execute actions both before and after the loading of files. May be that package can solve your problems. It can be used on a stand alone basis.

If you do not read German, the author has started the work on improving the English manual. He describes scrlfile on pages 248ff. You will find KOMA-Script at [CTAN](http://tug.org/ctan.html) and [BerliOS](http://developer.berlios.de/projects/koma-script3/).

Links to the new, improved, English manual you will find [here.](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf#page=360)

Comment: Love this solution! But for some reason I cannot make it work. I uploaded the package `scrlfile` and put the following commands

`\BeforePackage{hyperref}{\usepackage{float}

\floatstyle{boxed}

\restylefloat{figure}}`

But they are never executed (the figures are not boxed). Any insight?

Comment: @AlejandroDíaz-Caro No, I have never used the program. I suggest you ask the author, Markus Kohm, at http://komascript.de. Even if the site is in German, you can ask questions and get replies in English.

Comment: @AlejandroDíaz-Caro: Your comment is actually a new question, so I suggest you copy it to a new question to tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks. I just raised a [new question about this issue](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51094/using-beforepackage-to-load-a-package-before-hyperref-does-not-work).

Comment: Instead of using ``\BeforePackage{hyperref}`` to load ``float``, just load it ``\AfterClass{article}}``.  This is not the "right" way, but works.  (I don't yet understand how to fix ``\BeforePackage`` as that seems like the "right" way that does not work:-)  See [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51121/6903).