# Using \BeforePackage to load a package before hyperref does not work

Tags: hyperref, packages, incompatibility

I am using the `lipics` document class, which includes `hyperref`. I want to load the `float` package, which should be loaded before `hyperref`, without changing the document class. As suggested in [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50994/1856), I am trying to use the `KOMA-Script` called `scrlfile` (*cf.* page 199 [of the documentation](http://mirror.ibcp.fr/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/scrguien.pdf)), in the following way

```
\documentclass{lipics}
\usepackage{scrlfile}
\BeforePackage{hyperref}{
  \usepackage{float}
}
...
```

however it never loads the package.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try `\RequirePackage{scrfile}\BeforePackage{hyperref}{\usepackage{float}}\documentclass{lipics}`
`

Comment: There is something really odd. It rise an warning `You have requested package \`hyperref',
               but the package provides \`float'.` and the error `Command \c@float@type already defined.` However, if I do not put anything and try to use some commands from the package float (for example `\floatstyle{boxed}
\restylefloat{figure}`) I get the `undefined commands` error.
I am a bit lost.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem here is that you need to call `\BeforePackage{}` and related commands *before* the package is actually loaded so that the hooks can work.  This is what Marco's suggestion tries to do.

Unfortunately, you cannot load an additional package using `\BeforePackage{}` because, when `lipics` finally requests `hyperref`, loading `float` will call the `\ProvidesPackage{float}` declaration and LaTeX thinks that the wrong package is being provided.

I have found that it is best to use `\AfterPackage` or `\AfterClass`.  Why not just load the `float` package right after the `article` documentclass that `lipics` uses?

```
\RequirePackage{scrlfile}
\AfterClass{article}{
  \RequirePackage{float}
}

\documentclass[english]{lipics}
\begin{document}
Hi
\end{document}
```

If you really want to make `\BeforePackage{}` work, you can use the following hack

```
\BeforePackage{hyperref}{
  \let\oldProvidesPackage\ProvidesPackage   % Save original definition
  \def\ProvidesPackage#1[#2]{               % Redefine (simply)        
    \oldProvidesPackage#1[#2]               % Call original \ProvidesPackage
    \let\ProvidesPackage\oldProvidesPackage % restore original definitions
    \let\oldProvidesPackage\relax

    \RequirePackage{float}                  % Now load float
  }
}
```

This temporarily redefines `\ProvidesPackage` to first call the original version (which will tell LaTeX that `hyperref` is being provided as expected), then to load `float` after restoring the old definitions.

Comment: The first solution, load float after article, worked! Thanks!