# Using setspace package breaks footnotes link

Tags: hyperref, footnotes, setspace

The following code created a footnote, the problem is that in the produced pdf file clicking footnote reference `1` doesn't jump to footnote definition`1` in bottom of the page, instead, it jumps to the beginning of the pdf file. But if I remove the "\usepackage{setspace}" line everything works. Why is this and how to make it work as I expected? Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\tolerance=1000
\usepackage{setspace}
\title{temp}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks,%
  citecolor=black,%
  filecolor=black,%
  linkcolor=blue,%
  urlcolor=black
}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\section{Section 1}
\label{sec-1}
TeX is a computer program for typesetting documents, created by Donald Knuth. It
takes a suitably prepared computer file and converts it to a form which may be
printed on many kinds of printers, including dot-matrix printers, laser printers
and high-resolution typesetting machines. LaTeX is a set of macros for TeX that
aims at reducing the user's task to the sole role of writing the content, LaTeX
taking care of all the formatting process. A number of well-established
publishers now use TeX or LaTeX to typeset books and mathematical journals. It
is also well appreciated by users caring about typography, consistent
formatting, efficient collaborative writing and open formats.

\section{Section 2}
\label{sec-2}
TeX is a computer program for typesetting documents, created by Donald Knuth. It
takes a suitably prepared computer file and converts it to a form which may be
printed on many kinds of printers, including dot-matrix printers, laser printers
and high-resolution typesetting machines. LaTeX is a set of macros for TeX that
aims at reducing the user's task to the sole role of writing the content, LaTeX
taking care of all the formatting process. A number of well-established
publishers now use TeX or LaTeX to typeset books and mathematical journals. It
is also well appreciated by users caring about typography, consistent
formatting, efficient collaborative writing and open formats.

\section{Section 3}
\label{sec-3}
TeX is a computer program for typesetting documents, created by Donald Knuth. It
takes a suitably prepared computer file and converts it to a form which may be
printed on many kinds of printers, including dot-matrix printers, laser printers
and high-resolution typesetting machines. LaTeX is a set of macros for TeX that
aims at reducing the user's task to the sole role of writing the content, LaTeX
taking care of all the formatting process. A number of well-established
publishers now use TeX or LaTeX to typeset books and mathematical journals. It
is also well appreciated by users caring about typography, consistent
formatting, efficient collaborative writing and open formats.

\section{Test footnotes}
\label{sec-4}
This text has a footnote \footnote{See section \ref{sec-1}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you try loading `hyperref` *after* `setspace`?

Comment: See [Which packages should be loaded after hyperref instead of before?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/) for information.

Comment: Hi egrep,

Thank you very much, and yes loading hyperref after setspace addresses the
issue. I'm going to read the link you provided. This was my first post at Tex.SX
and I'm impressed by how fast my question gets correctly answered.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The package `setspace` modifies the standard definition of `\footnote` so that single spacing is used in the footnote texts. Also `hyperref` modifies `\footnote` so as to make the hyperlinks.

However, `hyperref` is generally agnostic about the definition of the commands it has to redefine for doing its job (there are many): it just takes the current definition and massages it a bit for adding the hyperlinks.

If you load the package `setspace` after `hyperref`, the modification made by the former overrides the change made by the latter. So the correct way is first loading `setspace` and then `hyperref`.

There are some packages that should be loaded *after* `hyperref`, you find a big list at [Which packages should be loaded after hyperref instead of before?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/) and `setspace` doesn't appear there.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks,%
  citecolor=black,%
  filecolor=black,%
  linkcolor=blue,%
  urlcolor=black
}

%\tolerance=1000 %%% Are you really sure?


\title{temp}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\section{Section 1}
\label{sec-1}
TeX is a computer program for typesetting documents, created by Donald Knuth. It
takes a suitably prepared computer file and converts it to a form which may be
printed on many kinds of printers, including dot-matrix printers, laser printers
and high-resolution typesetting machines. LaTeX is a set of macros for TeX that
aims at reducing the user's task to the sole role of writing the content, LaTeX
taking care of all the formatting process. A number of well-established
publishers now use TeX or LaTeX to typeset books and mathematical journals. It
is also well appreciated by users caring about typography, consistent
formatting, efficient collaborative writing and open formats.

\section{Section 2}
\label{sec-2}
TeX is a computer program for typesetting documents, created by Donald Knuth. It
takes a suitably prepared computer file and converts it to a form which may be
printed on many kinds of printers, including dot-matrix printers, laser printers
and high-resolution typesetting machines. LaTeX is a set of macros for TeX that
aims at reducing the user's task to the sole role of writing the content, LaTeX
taking care of all the formatting process. A number of well-established
publishers now use TeX or LaTeX to typeset books and mathematical journals. It
is also well appreciated by users caring about typography, consistent
formatting, efficient collaborative writing and open formats.

\section{Section 3}
\label{sec-3}
TeX is a computer program for typesetting documents, created by Donald Knuth. It
takes a suitably prepared computer file and converts it to a form which may be
printed on many kinds of printers, including dot-matrix printers, laser printers
and high-resolution typesetting machines. LaTeX is a set of macros for TeX that
aims at reducing the user's task to the sole role of writing the content, LaTeX
taking care of all the formatting process. A number of well-established
publishers now use TeX or LaTeX to typeset books and mathematical journals. It
is also well appreciated by users caring about typography, consistent
formatting, efficient collaborative writing and open formats.

\section{Test footnotes}
\label{sec-4}
This text has a footnote \footnote{See section \ref{sec-1}}
\end{document}
```

By the way, are you really sure about `\tolerance=1000`? It's quite a large value and you'll risk getting wide interword spaces. It's better to do

```
\usepackage{microtype}
```

(*before* loading `hyperref`).

Comment: Package `setspace` is an item in the section "Package Compatibility" of `hyperref`'s [README](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/README.pdf): Package order is `\usepackage{setspace}` before `\usepackage{hyperref}` as egreg has answered in more detail.

Comment: Sorry egrep about the \tolerance=1000 thing. It was a leftover that I should have deleted.

Comment: @York I have nothing to do with `egrep`, although I've written a package that uses regular expressions. ;-)

Comment: @egreg: What package is that, a LaTeX package? I'm pretty new to LaTeX, do you have really book/site to recommend?

Comment: @York It's called `regexpatch`, for modifying definitions of commands. You can try Nicola Talbot's [“LaTeX for Complete Novices”](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/)

Comment: @egrep: I'll definitely check out your package at some point. Thanks for referring the book, it looks nice but I'm not sure if I have time to read it page to page. Given my developer background, is there a really good reference manual?

Comment: @York -- (Assuming a TeX Live install) try `texdoc latex2e` for the core and `texdoc <package name>` for indivdidual packages (not all manuals were created equal, however); for the engines, try texdoc-ing `luatex`, `pdftex`, and `xetex` respectively.  If not on TeX Live, try the site [texdoc.net](texdoc.net).

Comment: @egreg: these command line doc are really nice, thanks a lot.