# Hyperlink from footnote mark to footnote body

Tags: hyperref, footnotes, incompatibility, back-referencing, setspace

When I click on a footnote mark in the PDF, it doesn't take me to the body of the footnote, but rather to the first page of the document.  I've heeded the advice at [Why are all of my footnotes hyperlinked to the titlepage?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71664/why-are-all-of-my-footnotes-hyperlinked-to-the-titlepage), to no avail. [`setspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace) seems to be the problem.

How can I resolve this?  MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{footnotebackref}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

This is some text\footnote{This is a footnote.}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you insert the label just after `\footnote{` or just before `}`?

Comment: What label do you mean?

Comment: @Rohan, well, to cite a footnote you first need to give a label to it.

Comment: @Rohan, ow, sorry. You are not citing it, just clicking on its number.

Comment: When I compile your example, it it takes me from the footnote marker to the footnote (bottom of page 2), and clicking on the footnote marker in the footnote takes me back to the footnote in the text body. So, the output is as expected. So I can't replicate your problem. Perhaps you could provide us with information on the `.log` file contents, and or the file versions you're using (see [Which package version am I using?](http://goo.gl/sBfU5X)).

Comment: @Werner I forgot to include the 'setspace' package, which I use in my actual document.  Use of this package seems to cause the issue.  Any ideas how to get around this?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue her and I found this article solving the problem:
[Using setspace package breaks footnotes link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188273/using-setspace-package-breaks-footnotes-link)

In short, include the setspace package before hyperref package.