# Footnote link stubbornly jumps to the title page

Tags: hyperref, footnotes

I have a little nasty problem: a footnote hyperlink doesn't lead me to current page footnote, but it jumps to the document title page.

I have already considered & tested several possible solutions ([Hyperlink from footnote mark to footnote body](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209672/hyperlink-from-footnote-mark-to-footnote-body), [Using setspace package breaks footnotes link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188273/using-setspace-package-breaks-footnotes-link)), but:

- including the 'setspace' package before 'hyperref' has no effect;
- disabling the 'hyperref' *hyperfootnotes* option (in original call to 'hyperref') leads to option clash.

I'm using the pdflatex compiler. Here are simplified code snippets:

% main.tex

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside, headinclude,footinclude]{book}
\usepackage{longtable} 
\input{book_structure.tex} % include the ''book_structure.tex'' file 
%which specifies the document structure and layout

% custom title page
\newcommand*{\titleTH}{\begingroup
\raggedleft 
\vspace*{\baselineskip} 
{\LARGE\bfseries Some book title}\\[\baselineskip] 
{\Large Version x.x.x}\par 
\endgroup}

\begin{document}
\titleTH % include the title page
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage

\chapter{System requirements}

\textbf{Supported operating systems:} Unix OS family 
(e.g. Mac OS X, Linux, FreeBSD) and Microsoft Windows OS family 
(e.g. 2000, 2003, XP, Vista, Seven, 8/8.1, 10). 

\textbf{CPU architectures:} x86 (x86-32, x86-64), ARMv7.

\textbf{CPU model:}\footnote{see our white paper on selection of 
hardware for LPR} selected individually (in accordance to 
number of recognition threads to be used on the server, 
video framerate and resolution). When adding one or more 
recognition threads, CPU load increases linearly. 

\end{document}
```

% book_structure.tex

```
\usepackage{arsclassica}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\renewcommand*\rmdefault{iwona} 

\usepackage[margin = 1.5cm]{geometry} 

\usepackage{setspace} % making 1.5 line spacing 
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage[T1, T2A]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}


%\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref} %option clash
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true, breaklinks=true,
 bookmarks=true, bookmarksnumbered, unicode=true, urlcolor=RoyalBlue, 
linkcolor=RoyalBlue
        }
```

If not fixing this bug, I would be satisfied with switching off the footnote hyperlinks, but, as said above, something goes wrong. Excuse me in advance for a must-be-trivial subject, I'm still a LaTeX newbie.

Does anybody have any considerations?

Comment: If `arsclassica` is not loaded, the linking is correct. `arsclassica` loads `classicthesis` which is a package that is multiple issues

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, thank you very much for your comment. Yes, excluding the 'arclassica' package from the simplified example solved the issue. But I have a few dependencies from 'classicthesis' in my real project, not to mention the output document design which I adore and don't want to lose.) I guess I will live with this bug. Anyway, as we've figured out what's wrong with the hyperlinks, I would gladly accept your answer if you wrote it down below.

Answer (score 2):

Similary to my answer to [Why are all of my footnotes hyperlinked to the titlepage?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71664/why-are-all-of-my-footnotes-hyperlinked-to-the-titlepage/72691#72691) this is a matter of package loading order. (One could argue this is a duplicate.) `setspace` is your bad boy here… What you need to be aware of is that `arsclassica` loads `classicthesis` which loads `hyperref`. This means you need to load `setspace` before `arsclassica`.

However, both `arsclassica` and `classicthesis` at least nowadays try loading `hyperref` with the option `hyperfootnotes=false` which made it tricky to reproduce the MWE. We also need to load `hyperref` before `arsclassica` to get them activated again.

`classicthesis` also loads `footmisc` which is not terribly compatible with `hyperref`. As can be seen in my linked answer it must be loaded before `hyperref`, too.  this means we need this loading order:

```
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{arsclassica}
```

Actually `classicthesis` does not load `footmisc` if it finds the command `\deffootnote`. The latter is a KOMA-Script command and available in KOMA-Script classes. What the maintainer of `classicthesis` didn't seem to be aware is that one can load the package `scrextend` for `\deffootnote` as well. So lets exchange `footmisc` and `scrextend` to be on the safer side:

```
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{arsclassica}
```

When we apply this to the MWE we get correctly hyperlinked footnotes (as of today 2021/01/04). I didn't use an external file `book_structure.tex` but simply included the code in the preamble and re-ordered:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside, headinclude,footinclude]{book}

\usepackage[T1, T2A]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}

\usepackage[margin = 1.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{setspace} % making 1.5 line spacing 
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes]{hyperref}
\usepackage{arsclassica}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\renewcommand*\rmdefault{iwona} 

\newcommand*{\titleTH}{%
  \begingroup
    \raggedleft 
    \vspace*{\baselineskip} 
    {\LARGE\bfseries Some book title}\\[\baselineskip]
    {\Large Version x.x.x}\par
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\titleTH
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage

\chapter{System requirements}

\textbf{Supported operating systems:} Unix OS family (e.g. Mac OS X, Linux,
FreeBSD) and Microsoft Windows OS family (e.g. 2000, 2003, XP, Vista, Seven,
8/8.1, 10).

\textbf{CPU architectures:} x86 (x86-32, x86-64), ARMv7.

\textbf{CPU model:}\footnote{see our white paper on selection of hardware for
  LPR} selected individually (in accordance to number of recognition threads
to be used on the server, video framerate and resolution). When adding one or
more recognition threads, CPU load increases linearly.

\end{document}
```