# `footnotebackref` not working correctly with `setspcase` in some condition

Tags: footnotes

Here is the [template](https://github.com/tompollard/phd_thesis_markdown).

partially working.

when I use `XeTeX`, `forward reference` is not working, `backward reference` is working fine.
when I use `LuaLaTeX`, `forward reference` linked to `References`, `backward reference` is working fine.

and I found why, the reason is `setspace`.

I googled it and [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188273/using-setspace-package-breaks-footnotes-link) and others saying about package loading order.
I changed package loading order to make it work but no luck.

I checked basic example that use both `setspace` and `footnotebackref`, it's no problem.

I can't find out what other thing which makes this bug.

I want to make it work.

Please help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please also include enough of a document so that we can see that forward references aren't working.  Does this happen with XeTeX, or other engines, or both?  (And check that `hypersetup` and `urlstyle` are not related to the error, and then take them out.)

Comment: Please work through https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/107497.  You've given us a lot of stuff that clearly isn't related to your problem.  And what are all those `$` doing in template.tex?  It looks like they're supposed to have been filled in by something else.

Comment: I can test this only XeTex because template is based on that, and I tried again after commented out all `hypersetup` and `urlstyle` thing, no difference. thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I can make `MWE` what you want because this template not only uses `tex`. I'm thinking how to improve my question... I think all those`$` things doing about `pandoc` thing.