# pdflatex warning with manyfoot and hyperref, absent in xelatex

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, manyfoot

The following code

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{manyfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote{R}[alph]
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
The default\footnote{Default} footnote works fine, but
manyfoot\footnoteR{Many foot} with pdflatex throws a warning. xelatex
run on the same code also does not throw a warning!
\end{document}
```

compiled using pdflatex throws the warning

> pdfTeX warning (dest): name{Hfootnote.2} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one

A similar question is addressed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16268/33945). However, the solution of loading hyperref as the last package still throws the error in the presence of [manyfoot](https://ctan.org/pkg/manyfoot). A [suggestion](https://texhax.tug.narkive.com/rpYYEger/pdftex-warning-with-hyperlinks) of including hyperfootnote=false, identifies the origin, but is not a solution when the hyperlinks are needed.

Strangely, if the code is run with xelatex, there is no warning and the PDF is generated with the links working fine.

How do we suppress the warning while keeping the hyperlinks active using pdflatex compiler?

Here are the output images for a quick reference:

[image: Many footnote mark]
[image: Footnote text]

Comment: I get no warning with XeLaTeX, but the link doesn't work.

Comment: I am sorry, you are correct.  I had checked only the plain footnote link (which works), but manyfoot link does not.

Answer (score 1):

you can try to add a target destination like this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{manyfoot}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\manyfoottarget{\makebox[0pt][r]{\hypertarget{Hfootnote.\theHfootnote}\quad}}
\patchcmd\MFL@fnoteplain{\rule}{\manyfoottarget\rule}{}{\fail}
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}
\DeclareNewFootnote{R}[alph]
\begin{document}
The default\footnote{Default}works fine, but
manyfoot\footnoteR{Many Foot} with pdflatex throws a warning. xelatex
run on the same code also does not throw a warning!
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Ulrike. it works. Can you please explain why such a definition of destination is required?