# Wrong page links with hyperref and manyfoot

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, manyfoot

hyperref links to the wrong page for footnotes generated by manyfoot.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{manyfoot}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\DeclareNewFootnote{C}
\begin{document}
 \tableofcontents
 \clearpage
 \section{Introduction}
 \clearpage
 \section{Background}
 Default citation \footnoteC{Links to page 1 instead of current page}
\end{document}
```

When the above code is compiled using pdflatex, the footnotemark is always hyperlinked (in PDF) to "Page 1", instead of the page where the footnotetext appears.

Answer (score 1):

This code leads to a warning

> pdfTeX warning (dest): name{Hfootnote.1} has been referenced but does
>   not exist, replaced by a fixed one

and solved in a related [issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/498968/33945) by [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer)

The same solution of defining a destination works for this as well. Hopefully, this will be fixed in the future releases of manyfoot.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\manyfoottarget{\makebox[0pt][r]{\hypertarget{Hfootnote.\theHfootnote
}\quad}}
\patchcmd\MFL@fnoteplain{\rule}{\manyfoottarget\rule}{}{\fail}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Please write a bug report to the maintainer of package `manyfoot` ...