# pdfTeX warning (dest): name{Hfootnote.x} has been referenced but does not exist , replaced by a fixed one

Tags: hyperref

I have an error that I cannot seem to fix.
Here is the minimal working example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
See \footnote{\footnote{text}}. 
\end{document}
```

This produces:

```
pdfTeX warning (dest): name{Hfootnote.2} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one
```

and I cannot see where the bug actually is.
I saw the messages [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16268/warning-with-footnotes-namehfootnote-xx-has-been-referenced-but-does-not-exi) and [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67989/pdftex-warning-has-been-referenced-but-does-not-exist-replaced-by-a-fixed-one) but that does not seem to match my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there are two bugs in the code.
First, the `footnote` is not properly defined. The code should be:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
See \footnote{text}.  % OK
\end{document}
```

But this was hidden in a bunch of text and I could not locate the bug because LaTeX does not produce any error message for this particular line.
Second, the message does not appear if hyperref is not used:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
See \footnote{\footnote{text}}.  % Not OK, but does not produce a warning
\end{document}
```

The previous code does not produce any warning or error message. The footnote is not properly displayed, however. We see that the footnote is empty.

[image: Empty footnote]

Comment: To nit pick, I don't think I would say "using hyperref is a bug".  I'd say that using hyperref hides that OP was misusing `\footnote`, which gets back to the first (and only bug).  But +1.