# pdflatex stops at \vec when using many packages lubuntu 23.04

Tags: pdftex, ubuntu

I have a very strange error on my lubutu (23.04 Lunar Lobster) using

pdflatex: 3.1412592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022/Debian)

Using `$\vec{a}$` leads to the following error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.71 (${\color{blue}\vec{a}
      }$)
```

The error can be ignored (pressing "R" for run), but is annoying and stresses me, because I have no clue where it comes from (and probably will stop on the server, after the next upgrade).

The same LaTeX Code (same inputs, same makros) runs without problem under
lubuntu 21.04 (Hirsute Hippo) using pdflatex 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020/Debian)

It can not be the imports or includes, but is most likely in one of the following packages has a prblem with the newest lubuntu; because, when I run a minimal example (without those packages) it compiles without problem. Probably also a problem with the order of my imports together with the newest pdflatex?

Here are my packages:

```
\usepackage{mciteplus}

\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide} %% Grid

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts} %% Zahlmengen Z, R, ...
%%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}

%% THEOREMS?
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


%%\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}

\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{makeidx}  
\usepackage{ifthen} 

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{listings}

%% Linebreaks in tabular-Zellen:
\usepackage{makecell}

%%\usepackage{color,fancyvrb,fancybox}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lastpage}
%%\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{pstricks}

%% bold typewriter font:
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage{enumerate}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{textcomp}


%% Kuchendiagramme
%%\usepackage{datapie}

%% für Aufgaben Hervorhebung
%%\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
%%\usepackage[standard,framed]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{mdframed}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

%\usepackage[tocindentauto]{tocstyle}
%\usepackage[tocindentauto]{tocbasic}
\usepackage{tocbasic}

%% für accentset wedge:
\usepackage{accents}

%% Würfel
\usepackage{epsdice}

%% Einbinden von GeoGebra Bildchen:
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\newcommand{\degre}{\ensuremath{^\circ}}

%% Hyperlinks
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
    bookmarks=true,
}

%% bugtracker (part of pgfplots) should be loaded AFTER "hyperref"
%% See: https://texblog.net/hyperref/ AND https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16268/warning-with-footnotes-namehfootnote-xx-has-been-referenced-but-does-not-exi
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}

%%\usepackage{fourier}  %% eg overarc (Bogenmaß)

%% For Background on title page (Züri Wappn)
\usepackage{eso-pic}
```

Any Ideas? Always keep in mind. Only on «Lobster and newest pdflatex» the error persists.

Comment: create a small but complete example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  Please turn this into a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).  The code you posted doesn't have a documentclass, doesn't use `\vec{a}`, and is not clear why your `\vec{a}` would be blue (is it in a hyperlink?).  Please also delete all of the packages that aren't needed to cause the error.

Comment: Here is the minimal (not) working example:

`\documentclass[twoside,14pt,a5paper]{extarticle}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{accents}
\begin{document}
Test $\vec{a}$
\end{document}`

Comment: It seams, that accents and ngerman do not compile together anymore with pdflatex: 3.1412592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022/Debian) which woked fine on the older verison.

Answer (score 1):

The following does no longer work ...:

```
\documentclass[twoside,14pt,a5paper]{extarticle} 
\usepackage{ngerman} 
\usepackage{accents} 
\begin{document} 
Test $\vec{a}$ 
\end{document}
```

... but it works fine, when I change the order of ngerman and accents:

```
\documentclass[twoside,14pt,a5paper]{extarticle} 
\usepackage{accents} 
\usepackage{ngerman} 
\begin{document} 
Test $\vec{a}$ 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually, both work. But the first example stops compiling, when it reaches the vector (\vec). When I press "R" (for run). It produces the required output. The second example runs without complaining.

Comment: Note that `ngerman` has been obsolete for many years (it hasn't been updated since 1998). Use `babel` and the proper option instead.

Comment: Works perfect using `\usepackage[german]{babel}` Thanks daleif.

Comment: @iGeeks Do note that if there is an error that requires you to press "R" (or any other letter), then the output is at best a guide to finding the error.  It cannot be assumed to be the required output.